# Unable to mount internal hard-drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

My computer has an SSD and an internal hard drive. I tried to set things up so that the hard drive would mount automatically on start-up. Unfortunately, something must have gone wrong because I can't mount it at all. I tried to put things back the way they were with the backup copy of fstab that I made before starting, but that didn't help.

When I try to access my hard drive using Files, I get the message:

```
Unable to access “47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23”

mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 10.
mount: /dev/sdb2 is already mounted or /mnt/47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23 busy
       /dev/sdb2 is already mounted on /
       /dev/sdb2 is already mounted on /mnt/47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23
```

Here are the contents of fstab.

> /dev/sda1
>
> UUID=3b0c4420-5c63-4878-be41-357c7c47dd7e
> /dev/disk/by-uuid/c126cc7a-ab90-46d2-aafb-c26f94a5bcb4 >/home/allan/Documents/ExtraDrive ext4 user,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
>
> /dev/sdb2
>
> UUID=47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23  none  swap  sw  0  0
> /dev/disk/by-uuid/47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23 /mnt/47862f8f->0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23 ext4 user,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 1
>
> /dev/sdb3
>
> UUID=3b0c4420-5c63-4878-be41-357c7c47dd7e
> /dev/disk/by-uuid/3b0c4420-5c63-4878-be41-357c7c47dd7e >/home/allan/Documents/ExtraDrive ext4 user,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs->show 0 0
>
> Connect to Cabinet
> //cabinet.usask.ca/work$ /mnt/cabinet cifs username=ajm195,noauto,user 0 0

This is the output of lsblk -f:

> NAME   FSTYPE LABEL  UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
> sdb
> ├─sdb2 ext4   Ubuntu 47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23 /mnt/47862f8f-0d45-4f1
> ├─sdb3 swap          3b0c4420-5c63-4878-be41-357c7c47dd7e [SWAP]
> └─sdb1
> sr0
> sda
> └─sda1

Here is the output of df -k:

> Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
> udev             1961612        0   1961612   0% /dev
> tmpfs             396648    16552    380096   5% /run
> /dev/sdb2      111117096 96395236   9054328  92% /
> tmpfs            1983240    33852   1949388   2% /dev/shm
> tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
> tmpfs            1983240        0   1983240   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
> cgmfs                100        0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
> tmpfs             396648       80    396568   1% /run/user/1000

I'm running version 16.04. I would greatly appreciate any help resolving this.

Comment: What is the contents of /etc/fstab and the outputs of lsblk -f and df -k

Comment: `lsblk -f` requires super-suer privileges, so please prepend it with `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added the contents of fstab and the output from lsblk -f and df -k.

Comment: I was able to get some in-person help, and the problem is now resolved. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message, your fstab probably contain a duplicate entry for the disk having the UUID 47862f8f-0d45-4f1e-94f1-bb9ce2b88d23, and you would have to edit your /etc/fstab file to correct it.

If you're not sure about how to mount properly you disk, you can have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Posting your /etc/fstab would help confirming this and editing my answer to get it more detailed on how to fix.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've updated my question with the contents of my fstab.

Comment: @AllanMcPherson Okay I'm starting to figure it out, I would also need the output of `blkid` to provide an answer

Comment: I was able to get some in-person help, and I have it working again. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Good to know it's fixed :) You're welcome